# Cannot resolve nunjucks template

Tags: node.js, nunjucks

Created a simple script to attempt to render a nunjucks template (Both the contact content and layout template are in the `src` directory:

```
 let fs = require('fs');
 let nj = require('nunjucks');

 var contact = fs.readFileSync('./src/contact.html','utf8');
 nj.configure('src');
 let result = nj.render(contact);
 console.log(result);
```

The contact content looks like this:

```
  {% set title = 'Contact' %}
  {% extends '_layout.html' %}
  {% block content %}
  <h1>Test Template</h1>
  {% endblock %}
```

The layout template looks like this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE>
  <html>
  <head>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </body>
    </html>
```

When running the script it throws:

```
    Error: template not found: {% set title = 'Contact' %}
    {% extends '_layout.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <h1>Test Template</h1>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the API wrong.  Instead of reading in the file and telling Nunjucks to render it do this:

```
        nj.configure('src');
        let result = nj.render('contact.html');
```

Bot the `contact.html` and `_template.html` files are in the `src` directory.  Almost too easy :)

Comment: Wouldn't you also pass data to `nj.render()` so the template engine can use that data to fill in things in your template?  Like where does the `{{title}}` value come from?

Comment: {% set title = 'Contact' %}